# How to add pic below in GitHub?

Tags: github

How can I add build badges to my GitHub README?

[image]

Comment: It's just Markdown - see lots of images here: https://shields.io/

Comment: How to change the text in the build badges？

Comment: The text is generally fixed, but some badge services may allow you to change it using a query string parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a Markdown image and link.

**Example :**

```
[![Build status](https://ci.appveyor.com/api/projects/status/yc3leb1t5t6ue01i?svg=true)](your link)
```

**Result:**

[image: Build status]

---

You can learn from here : [Basic writing and formatting syntax - User Documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax/#using-emoji).

Comment: It looks like you're posting all of your answers in "stylistic" lower-case (or perhaps you are using a mobile device to post). Please try to apply the usual case rules for English - there is always an upper case initial, and the personal pronoun "I" is always upper case too. This will reduce the amount of editing that is necessary on your posts.